# vue2.7 v-if not working with script setup, does vue2.7 above not support this syntax?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="handleClick">toggle</button>
    <span v-if="isToggled()">
      hidden message
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const sets = ref<Set<number>>(new Set())

const isToggled = computed(() => () => sets.value.has(1))

function handleClick() {
  sets.value.add(1)
}
</script>
```

expect: click the button and show the `hidden message`
current: nothing happened...

Vue version: 2.7.7
vite: 3.0.2
typescript: 4.7.4

> The basic `npm init vue@2` project, and run above code in `App.vue` with `npm run dev`

Answer (score 2):

okey...
I realized that vue2.7.x is not use Proxy yet, so `Set` is not supported with reactivity.

solution: just add a reactive data as condition...

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="handleClick">toggle</button>
    <span v-if="isToggled()">
      hidden message
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const sets = ref<Set<number>>(new Set())
const fake = ref<number>(1)


const isToggled = computed(() => () => fake.value && sets.value.has(1))
// same as function isToggled() { ... }

function handleClick() {
  fake.value++
  sets.value.add(1)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Set` are not reactive in Vue 2.7, you could try the following workaround :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="handleClick">toggle</button>
    <span v-if="isToggled">
      hidden message
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const sets = ref<Set<number>>(new Set())

const isToggled = ref(false)

function handleClick() {
  sets.value.add(1)
  isToggled.value=sets.value.has(1)
}
</script>
```

**Old Note for Vue 3:**

The computed properties are used as normal variables without using brackets `()` :

```html
    <span v-if="isToggled">
      hidden message
    </span>
```

and remove the extra `()=>` in computed callback :

```js
const isToggled = computed(()  => sets.value.has(1))
```

The computed property that returns a function is used when there's an argument passed, otherwise use a normal one :

```html
    <span v-if="isToggled(1)">
      hidden message
    </span>
```

```js
const isToggled = computed(() => (n)  => sets.value.has(n))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I found the primary cause of this problem is the Vue2 not use `Proxy` yet, so the `Set` type is not reactivity.
btw: I also tried your solution, it's not working